# Database connection and die issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, die

```
 if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
        $data = User::get(['id','first_name','last_name']);
        return View::make('index')->with('data',$data);
    }
    else{
        $request->session()->put('error','Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration.');
        return view::make('errors.503');  
    }
```

My `else` part is not working while DB is not connect. How to handle all DB connection and die exception in laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()` checks the name from your configuration, that must be the reason why always evaluates to true

Try instead `DB::connection()->getPdo();`, it will throw an exception (use try/catch) if fails.

edit:

```
try {
    DB::connection()->getPdo();
    $data = User::get(['id','first_name','last_name']);
    return View::make('index')->with('data',$data);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    $request->session()->put('error','Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration.');
    return view::make('errors.503');  
}
```

Comment: I try (try/catch). but not able to solve issue can you tell me the proper way of try/catch? @vivoconunxino

Comment: `This page isn’t working

localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` This error is coming.